# How did I earn "Steeling with Feeling" without earning "To The Smithy!"?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements, technical-issues

View the screenshots below.  It shows that I earned `Steeling with Feeling: Level up the Blacksmith` **BUT** I did NOT earn `To The Smithy!: Acquire the Blacksmith`

[image]

[image]

I am assuming that this is a glitch, or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first few days after the game launched, there were a multitude of achievement glitches.  If your game was interrupted around the time you earned that achievement, it may not have synced properly.

The "Lore" achievements in particular were quite buggy.  Blizzard has said that they're aware of the problem and are working to fix it.

From a recent [forum post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5150106401):

> Aside from the tremendous number of players simultaneously logging in to the game, one of the launch-day service issues was linked to the achievement system. Some players began to notice early on that achievements were either not being earned properly, or not being saved between multiple logins. We’re investigating this issue and will provide a specific update as soon as possible.

For now, sit tight, and hopefully later the glitches will be fixed and there will be some way to repair these buggy achievements.

Comment: This will probably be rather localized, but you can watch other people complain on twitter: https://twitter.com/#!/search/%40bashiok%20achievement

Comment: Watching people complain on Twitter is *always* fun.